# Cypress run in command line with multiple config params

Tags: cypress

I am trying to pass multiple config params in Cypress via command line (e.g. I want to disable video and screenshots), but want to do it only via command line:

```
cypress run --config video=false
```

This works, but how can I also pass `screenshotOnRunFailure=false`?

```
cypress run --config video=false --config screenshotOnRunFailure=false
```

This will ignore the second config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use comma to separate the two

```js
cypress run --config video=false,screenshotOnRunFailure=false
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize I can put it together separated by comma